# Windows NT cannot browse Windows Server 2008

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008, windows

Windows NT 4.0 cannot browse Windows server 2008 R2, but i can ping it. But on Win Server 2003 can browse fine (ask for username and password).

Sofar i tried:

```
Windows NT 4.0 has SP6a, ie6, DSClient and i set NTML2 (LMCompatibilityLevel) on 3

Windows Server 2008:
gpedit.msc : -Network security:LAN Manager authentication level properties (set on  Send NTML v2 response only. Refuse LM&NTLM)
             -Microsoft network server:Digital sign communications (always)  (set on  disabled)
             -Computer Conf -> Administrative Templates -> System -> Net Logon -> Allow cryptography algorithms compatible with win NT 4.0  (set on enabled)

Active directory Users and Computers  -> Builtin -> Pre-Windows 2000 Compatible Access (i add Win NT user and tried also with domain user and it doesn't work)
```

The error i get is: `The network path was not found`.

Any idea what it might be?

Comment: Why are you using an operating system releases SIXTEEN YEARS ago, that's been out of support for nearly a decade? There's just no excuse, this site is for professional sysadmins, I wouldn't know what to describe doing something so dangerous is but it's far from professional.

Comment: The Win NT os is an old CNC machine (six of them), which, for now, cannot replace by new OS. Belive me, i would change it, if i could.

Comment: @Chopper3: Labs, workshops and factories are still full with those old machines that just work fine. In a datacenter, this stuff has no place, but elsewhere replacing the control computer with a newer one means you have to pay really large sums to replace the controlled machinery as well. Keeping this systems running often falls into the realm of the system administrators (as I know from firsthand experience).

Comment: @Chopper3 NT4 is antique, yes. But sometimes we do have to support them. That doesn't mean we are no professionals. I'm dealing with a similar situation in 2 factories. There is simply no alternative for this tech. Of course they only get on a seperate VLAN. The target server is dual-NIC with one in this LAN and the other one connected to the regular LAN. And it doesn't bridge: Only a share open to both sides to transfer data and the NT4 VLAN firewalled of for anything else.

Comment: We had to use the ol' sneaker net to get ours to work (Win 3.1)... hope you still have some 3 1/2" floppies lying around.  Though, I did ask a similar question a while back and got some insight on. http://superuser.com/questions/423061/is-there-a-modern-browser-that-runs-on-windows-3-1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Can I propose an alternative solution?

If your NT4.0 boxen are controlling CNC hardware, I'm going to assume that all you need to do is be able to copy the command files (or whatever).

How about putting IIS on the Windows 2k8 server, then you'd be able to use Internet Explorer (or similar) to browse the file listing, and download stuff from it.

You could even use HTTP authentication backed by the Active Directory to get the user authentication bit.

You've probably got little to no chance of getting a proper file share working, as the protocols have changed so much, probably beyond compatibility, but HTTP 1.1 should still be a possible mechanism.

That said, if you wanted bi-directional file transfers, FTP is still a possibility..

Comment: IE 6 definitely speaks HTTP 1.1.

Comment: I create web site with directory browsing and it's working fine. It's easy and smooth solution :), thanks for reply.

Comment: @JanOlMajti Your next task is to pass a command file to the CNC system to produce a large hammer. You may then use said hammer to beat the manufacturer of the CNC system until they support an operating system made in the current century. :-)

Comment: Someone should do it long time ago

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative might be to set up a small Linux VM and set up a Samba(3) server. It should be possible to configure it to talk to NT4.

Comment: If nothing of all answers will work, i will try this solution, thanks

Answer (score 2):

NT4 SP4 and newer is able to talk NTLMv2 as far as I know, so that shouldn't be the problem.

Basically, two things are required to happen for this to work:
1. Your NT4 box needs to be able to talk to a domain controller
2. Your NT4 box needs to be able to talk SMB with your file server

Could you try the steps outlined in this document? It's basically 4 GPO settings that need adjusting on the domain controller level. I'm assuming the NT4 box is a member for the same domain/forest as the file server. Also any event log entries on your NT4 client regarding unsuccessful domain logons would be of value.

here's the link:
[Modify Security Policies in Default Domain Controllers Policy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731654%28WS.10%29.aspx)

Comment: I did all from the link and still no luck, thanks for reply

Comment: Can you browse other servers from the NT4 box? are you able to reach the netlogon share on your domain controllers? Are other computers able to reach the problematic share?

Comment: With NT i can browse WS 2000 and WS2003, only WS 2008 R2 not. Ping is working.

Answer (score 1):

It has been a while when this question was put it but there are plenty of embedded Windows NT4 machines in Production enviroments!

Had the same issue and solved it:
Subnetmask of NT4 machine was outdated.
DNS Servers where not entered.

After updating this I could create a share to a Windows 2008 R2 Server (getting rid of the 2003 Server)

Answer (score 1):

Check Following things on Both side the NT Machine and the Server (win server 2008/2016/2019):

1. The server must support SMB version 1 (no other chance with SMB): https://support.microsoft.com/dede/
   help / 2696547 / detect-enable-disable-smbv1-smbv2-smbv3-in-windows-and-windows-server
2. The authentication method must be: LM, NTLM or NTLM V2 (not higher than NTLM V2)

3.Determining the version and settings of NTLM on the server side: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previousversions/
windows / it-pro / windows-2000-server / cc960646 (v = technet.10)? redirectedfrom = MSDN
If NTLMV2 is active: create a registration key on the machine (see machine)

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa
LMCompatibilityLevel = 5 (REG_DWORD) (forces ntlmv2)
NoLmHash = 1 (REG_DWORD)

4. NBT (NETBIOS over TCP / IP) must be activated: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/323357/how-to-configure-tcp-ipnetworking-
   while-netbios-is-turned-off-on-a-se
5. The following server ports for NETBIOS must be accessible: 137 / udp, 138 / udp, 139 / tcp
6. The server system time must not exceed 30 minutes. Deviate from the machine → mostly correction on the Machine required or activation of NTP Deamon.