# Is it possible to use Win XP as a DHCP server in a network?

Tags: windows-xp, dhcp

Is it possible to use Win XP as a DHCP server in a network ?
Does Win XP can give automatic IP addresses to clients in a network ??

Answer (score 4):

Possible - Yes
Advisable - No

Check your watch, it's 2015 dude! XP's not supported at all, this site's for professional sysadmins, who inherently build and use supportable systems.

Comment: Should your advice be applied to other similar questions (related to legacy systems)? For example:
http://serverfault.com/questions/532879/windows-nt-cannot-browse-windows-server-2008

Comment: I did, look at the first comment :)

Answer (score 0):

You need a server OS for this or if you NEED to use WinXP, there might be some third party programs out there to do it, however, I don't recommend that.

A Windows Server or corporate firewall (ASA, Dell SonicWall) can also take care of that for you.